# Getting the Contents of a CSV File Inside ContentVersion Object in Salesforce

Tags: apex, contentversion

How can I get the body of a file stored in `ContentVersion` object in salesforce? I've attempted to query its contents but seems that there is no field holding the body value.

`SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,FileExtension,Title,VersionData FROM ContentVersion`

I tried using the `VersionData` field but all its returning is an encoded file data.

Answer (score 1):

The `VersionData` field of `ContentVersion` contains the base64 encoded data of your csv file.

You will have to decode it using apex code to get comma separated values.

```
Blob b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(contentVersionObj.VersionData);
System.debug(b.toString());
```

Comment: Decoding VersionData would result in a `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void base64Decode(Blob) from the type System.EncodingUtil` error. You can instead use the `toString()` method for VersionData, similar to the answer below (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/274289/12151)

Answer (score 1):

Probably a late reply, but you don't need to convert it with the EncodingUtil class.

As an example, this is the way to get a csv from a content version:

```
final ContentVersion cv = [SELECT VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :docId AND IsLatest = true];
final String csvContents = cv.VersionData.toString();
final String[] csvLines = csvContents.split('\n');
```